# Running ml-10m dataset using Apache-Flink als but get only 13 predictions

Tags: apache-flink

While using Apache Flink als with the following code:

```
val env=ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val inputDS: DataSet[String]=env.readTextFile("/home/master/dataset/ml-10m/trainset")
val inputDS1: DataSet[Tuple3[Int,Int,Double]] = inputDS.map{
      t =>
      val split = t.split("::")
      Tuple3(split(0).toInt, split(1).toInt, split(2).toDouble)                               
          }
val als = ALS()
         .setIterations(5)
         .setNumFactors(10)
         .setBlocks(300)
         // Set the other parameters via a parameter map
         val parameters = ParameterMap()                                                                        
        .add(ALS.Lambda, 0.2)                                                                                 
        .add(ALS.Seed, 42L)                                                                               
        // Calculate the factorization                                                                                          
        als.fit(inputDS1, parameters)
  val inputttestDS: DataSet[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/master/dataset/ml-10m/testset")                                                                                                       
  val testingDS: DataSet[Tuple2[Int,Int]] = inputttestDS.map{                                                                                                      
          t =>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          val split = t.split("::")                                                                                                                            
          Tuple2(split(0).toInt, split(1).toInt)
}    
val predictedRatings=als.predict(testingDS)
predictedRatings.print()
predictedRatings.writeAsText("path to result")
env.execute()
```

But the result only predict the last 13 data in to the result file.
Is the data too big for apache flink using in idea (For train dataset, it has 8000000 observations. Besides, test dataset has 20000000 observations) ? And the data frame is "userid::itemid::rating::timestamp". Besides, my computer'ram is 8G. Or I have some mistake in my code? Please tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it is my dataset's problem. In my test dataset, It only have 13 observations which its userid appear in training dataset. So, it only make prediction on those data.